# pivot dynamic query and store results to table

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic, pivot

I have a dynamic query where the number of columns vary. I want to store the results into a table for further processing.

I added an `insert into` clause to store the results into a table, but I'm getting a syntax error.

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14 Incorrect syntax near ')'
```

I'm using MS SQL server management studio 2008 R2.

Here's my query:

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#datesTemp') IS NOT NULL BEGIN   DROP TABLE #datesTemp END 
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @startDate datetime

SET @startDate = '2005-01-01'

;with dates as
(
  select @startdate datelist, 1 sp
  union all
  select dateadd(month, 1, datelist), sp+1
  from dates
  where sp+1 <= 122 -- change this number 5 to the number of months you need
)
select   sp,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), datelist, 120) as MONTHANDYEAR 
into #datesTemp
from dates 
option (maxrecursion 122)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(monthandyear) 
                    from #datesTemp
                    group by monthandyear, sp
                    order by sp
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colNames = STUFF((SELECT  ', isnull(' + QUOTENAME(monthandyear)+', 0) as '+QUOTENAME(monthandyear)
                    from #datesTemp
                    group by monthandyear, sp
                    order by sp
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'')


set @query = 'select * into recmonth_temp from 
            (SELECT FIPS, DATA_TYPE,' + @colNames + ' 
             from 
             (
                select FIPS, DATA_TYPE,REC_MONTH, TOTAL_RECORDS 
                from REPORTING.DBO.APEX_CUMULATIVE_SUMMARY_ALL_STAGING_NEW A join member1.dbo.fipscode F
                on a.fips = f.fipscode

            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(TOTAL_RECORDS)
                for REC_MONTH in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p) '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: And what is the syntax error that you're receiving?

Comment: oh sorry...syntax error - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: You are missing an alias after the last ). You need to alias all subqueries and derived tables.

Comment: I figured it out myself after several trials. Thank you very much for the help. It is much appreciated.